# Creating a smaller UIPickerView for use in table

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I'm trying to create a smaller UIPickerView for use in a table and I can't work out how to make the actual control resize correctly.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like the following:
[image]

I am creating my picker in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIPickerView *myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                  CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 85)];

    myPickerView.delegate = self;
    myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [myPickerView selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:myPickerView];
```

No matter what I set the height to, I get the same size UIPickerView. The first image is with 85 for the height. The second image is with 200 for the height.

The one thing I can do is change the cell height, but if I do this and set the height of the UIPickerView to the same value as the cell height, the picker isn't centred in the cell and the actual touch control point is near the bottom of the cell. The final image in this post illustrates this...

**Result of "CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 85)"**
[image: GRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 85)]

**Result of "CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 200)"**
[image: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 200)]

**Picker Frame and Cell Height set to 100**
[image: Picker Frame and Cell Height set to 100]

Answer (score 1):

Try to shrink the "height" of the UIPickerView

```
myPickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7, 0.7);
```

Comment: That makes the picker disappear entirely. If I change the scale to (1, 0.7) then it does make it shorter (with squished text but I can fix that with images), but it still doesn't place it any higher in the cell - so I get what you see at http://imgur.com/fMfXwDa

Comment: sorry for "0" (instead "1").. mistyped; I've checked now in iOS7 - you have right; I'm still using this "trick" for iOS5-6 and is working well; We must find a new "peaceful" solution for iOS7

Comment: I've checked again (Xcode 5.0.1) and the code above is working well